# Are there any good statistics on students who are second generation in higher education?

Tags: united-kingdom, reference-request

We do a lot of statistical analysis on students who are first-generation HE; the first generation in their family to attend University.

But are there any similar studies on students who are *second-generation* HE - ie, whose parents were first-generation?

Comment: Have you a reason for asking this? I find it hard to think of a justification for the research?

Comment: @Buffy Well, it might be interesting to compare the two groups.  (But I'm a computer scientist, not a sociologist.)

Comment: @BobBrown, "might be interesting" is hardly compelling. Is there any action item you think might be suggested by the research. On the face of it, it just sounds like a study for the sake of a study. I could be wrong and would like to know where I'm wrong. I note for the record here that we now have Mr. Green, and Mr. Brown. Colorful.

Comment: @Buffy  Well, I have a statistician friend who could probably get half-a-dozen papers out of such a comparison.  What?  Not that kind of action item?  We, or at least I, assume that students with college-educated parents do better.  Is it true?  Do generations matter? If so, what causes the differences, and what can we do to help the disadvantaged group?

Comment: @BobBrown, I suspect that some of the first generation research also tries to answer the question of comparing first generation v other than first get, but probably not singling out second. That is my quandary. I was first generation and did well. My son was second and didn't like the academic life so didn't do well. My daughter is a professor. But if the last ten generations of your family are college educated there might be a relationship. Though some kids will balk at following into the family "business" (i.e. academia).

Comment: The main justification is a theory proposed to me recently: first-generation students are often a success within their family. Second-generation students often have grown up with their parents having the benefit of HE, but not yet having a financial cushion against their failure. So while the first-generation students can make their families proud if they pass, second-generation students can only "continue as before" by passing, or kill the dream if they fail.

Comment: @Buffy “Might be interesting” is a **perfect** reason for asking this question. We are not evaluating a grant proposal here.

Comment: @Buffy just an example: how fast do differences in educational opportunities diminish across generations?

Comment: This is a standard reference request and pertinent to Academia, so it's squarely on-topic. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is studies that control for parental education. If none of them have a university education then they are the first generation, if one of them has a university generation then they are not the first generation. So the "effect" of that variable makes the comparison you are after. Parental education is a fairly standard variable in this literature, so you should be able to find such references quickly enough.

Comment: Parents receiving high education does not guarantee they are the first generation. They could be the second, or even third generation themselves. Student's parents receiving HE only indicates the student is not the first generation.

Comment: The OP defined first generation as being the first to enter tertiary education, so parents receiving higher education guarantees they are *not* the first generation. I suspect you mean "Parents receiving high education does not guarantee they are the second generation.", and add one generation to all mentions of generation afterwards.

Comment: In that case, that is in principle true, and that is why I said "not the first generation" instead of "second generation". However, in practice when we go that far back in time there are very few people who got that level of education. Maybe in the USA, where you had a noticeable rise in university enrollment after WWII, but in most other places the big rise in university enrollment started around the '60s. Moreover what is the effect of your grandparents or great grandparents on your education after controlling for your parent's education?

Comment: I mean parents receiving HE does not guarantee _the parents themselves_ are the first generation. The OP is asking _studies on students who are second-generation HE_.Parental education is not sufficient for that info.

Comment: BTW, we are not talking about what's happening in Academia. I believe the question is off-topic.

Comment: No, per the definition of OP: first generation means parents have no HE, second generation means parents have HE, third generation parents and grandparents have HE, etc. So parent without HE guarantees first generation. parents with HE could mean, second, third, etc. generation, but in practice it will almost always be second, with the possible exception of USA where educational expansion happened a bit earlier.

Comment: The OP specifically asked _students who are second-generation HE - ie, **whose parents were first-generation**?_

Comment: I think we somehow agree, but approach it differently and we would solve this in seconds if we were to talk face to face.